# How Do I return to the top of the loop Python

Tags: loops, python-3.x, if-statement

I need some help on returning to the top of the loop in python I know about the break statement but I do not know if its helpful at all.

Here is my code:

```
import random

Which_Dice= input("What dice do you want? 4,6 or 12")

if input(Which_Dice)!=("4","6","12"):
    print("Please input the number 4,6 or 12")

elif int(Which_Dice)== 4:
    print(int(Which_Dice), "sided dice thrown", "score",random.randint(0,5))

elif int(Which_Dice)== 6:
    print(int(Which_Dice), "sided dice thrown", "score",random.randint(0,7))

elif int(Which_Dice)==12:
    print(int(Which_Dice), "sided dice thrown", "score",random.randint(0,13))
```

Comment: Well, you don't have a loop anywhere in your code so that's why you can't "return to the top of the loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is run that part of your program over and over (effectively jumping back up to the top), you can use a while true loop to accomplish that:

```
import random

while True:

    Which_Dice= input("What dice do you want? 4,6 or 12")

    if input(Which_Dice)!=("4","6","12"):
        print("Please input the number 4,6 or 12")

    elif int(Which_Dice)== 4:
        print(int(Which_Dice), "sided dice thrown", "score",random.randint(0,5))

    elif int(Which_Dice)== 6:
        print(int(Which_Dice), "sided dice thrown", "score",random.randint(0,7))

    elif int(Which_Dice)==12:
        print(int(Which_Dice), "sided dice thrown", "score",random.randint(0,13))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no loop in your code but maybe this will help?

```
def callme():
    Which_Dice= input("What dice do you want? 4,6 or 12")
    .
    .

callme()
callme()
```

or look into for or while loops.